# Set Text Controls align center in wix toolset

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I'm writing my Wix installer and encountered some UI issue.
I have a Dialog with a Text Control inside that attached to a Property and can contains different length of text in that Property.

The issue is that I set this Property with large width and height and depends on the text length it could be aligned correctly to the Width and Height of the Dialog or it could be on the top of the Dialog because it's only 2 words.

Medium text length:

[image: Medium text length]

Long text length

[image]

Same dialog but look funny at first image and not very clear and second image.

How can I align the text to be center whenever the text is not filling the whole Control?